# Implementación WebService SII en .Net Core (Sistema información inmediato) AEAT

Tags: soap, asp.net-core, aeat-sii

Actualmente estoy tratando de conectarme al servicio de la AEAT de Facturas Emitidas correspondiente al SII.

Trabajo sobre .NET Core 1.1 y me veo incapaz de conectarme al WDSL que proporciona la agencia tributaria.

Una vez añado la referencia a mi proyecto me indica que varios namespaces no pueden ser resueltos (System.Web.Services por ejemplo).

Según he podido leer:

> System.Web.Services is a predecessor of WCF. Since even the mighty WCF is considered deprecated on the server side, do not expect System.Web.Services to be available in .NET Core or the concrete App Model ASP.NET Core 1.0. Their namespaces even start with Microsoft.AspNetCore. SOAP is considered deprecated in favor of REST and JSON. Microsoft will tell you: Use the .NET Framework but not .NET Core.

Con esto mis esperanzas van desapareciendo, así que mi pregunta es, ¿alguien ha conseguido conectar con el SII sin utilizar el WDSL, en .NET Core?

Gracias.

Comment: Pásate por clubdelphi que allí llevamos discutiendo sobre esto desde la implementación hace casi 2 años y cada uno tiene su lenguaje. Si mal no recuerdo Neutro lo hizo en .NET

Comment: Sabes que tipo de servicio es el SSI? es wcf? Por otro lado, por que no .net core 2?

Comment: Gracias ManuelRobles , me pasaré.

Hola Pikoh , uso OpenIddict para el token de sesión de los usuarios y aún no es compatible con .NET Core 2.